# Where can I find the JBoss source for the implementation of 12.1 and 12.2 of the servlet spec?

Tags: java, servlets, jboss, servlet-3.0

http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-oth-JSpec/servlet-3_0-final-spec.pdf

This would be under Chapter 12: Mapping Requests to Servlets. I reviewed the Maven repository for JBoss, and although the spec interface is available I can't seem to find the underlying implementation of 12.1 and 12.2 with regard to servlet url pattern matching. I'm interested in reviewing how the expressions are mapped to the rules for another project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm considering Tomcat 7.0.42. Links in below answer point to 7.0.42 source code in grepcode.com.

The servlet mappings are during application startup parsed and added as `Wrapper` inside [`org.apache.tomcat.util.http.mapper.Mapper#addWrapper()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-coyote/7.0.42/org/apache/tomcat/util/http/mapper/Mapper.java#Mapper.addWrapper%28org.apache.tomcat.util.http.mapper.Mapper.ContextVersion,java.lang.String,java.lang.Object,boolean,boolean%29) whose source code is copypasted here (note: the term "wrapper" stands here basically for "a mapped servlet"):

```
360     protected void addWrapper(ContextVersion context, String path,
361             Object wrapper, boolean jspWildCard, boolean resourceOnly) {
362 
363         synchronized (context) {
364             Wrapper newWrapper = new Wrapper();
365             newWrapper.object = wrapper;
366             newWrapper.jspWildCard = jspWildCard;
367             newWrapper.resourceOnly = resourceOnly;
368             if (path.endsWith("/*")) {
369                 // Wildcard wrapper
370                 newWrapper.name = path.substring(0, path.length() - 2);
371                 Wrapper[] oldWrappers = context.wildcardWrappers;
372                 Wrapper[] newWrappers =
373                     new Wrapper[oldWrappers.length + 1];
374                 if (insertMap(oldWrappers, newWrappers, newWrapper)) {
375                     context.wildcardWrappers = newWrappers;
376                     int slashCount = slashCount(newWrapper.name);
377                     if (slashCount > context.nesting) {
378                         context.nesting = slashCount;
379                     }
380                 }
381             } else if (path.startsWith("*.")) {
382                 // Extension wrapper
383                 newWrapper.name = path.substring(2);
384                 Wrapper[] oldWrappers = context.extensionWrappers;
385                 Wrapper[] newWrappers =
386                     new Wrapper[oldWrappers.length + 1];
387                 if (insertMap(oldWrappers, newWrappers, newWrapper)) {
388                     context.extensionWrappers = newWrappers;
389                 }
390             } else if (path.equals("/")) {
391                 // Default wrapper
392                 newWrapper.name = "";
393                 context.defaultWrapper = newWrapper;
394             } else {
395                 // Exact wrapper
396                 if (path.length() == 0) {
397                     // Special case for the Context Root mapping which is
398                     // treated as an exact match
399                     newWrapper.name = "/";
400                 } else {
401                     newWrapper.name = path;
402                 }
403                 Wrapper[] oldWrappers = context.exactWrappers;
404                 Wrapper[] newWrappers =
405                     new Wrapper[oldWrappers.length + 1];
406                 if (insertMap(oldWrappers, newWrappers, newWrapper)) {
407                     context.exactWrappers = newWrappers;
408                 }
409             }
410         }
411     }
```

While dealing with incoming HTTP requests, all the magic of finding the servlet by mapping starts in [`org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter#postParseRequest()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina/7.0.42/org/apache/catalina/connector/CoyoteAdapter.java#CoyoteAdapter.postParseRequest%28org.apache.coyote.Request,org.apache.catalina.connector.Request,org.apache.coyote.Response,org.apache.catalina.connector.Response%29).

```
647        connector.getMapper().map(serverName, decodedURI, version,
648                                  request.getMappingData());
649        request.setContext((Context) request.getMappingData().context);
650        request.setWrapper((Wrapper) request.getMappingData().wrapper);
```

Line 647 invokes indirectly [`org.apache.tomcat.util.http.mapper.Mapper #internalMapWrapper()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-coyote/7.0.42/org/apache/tomcat/util/http/mapper/Mapper.java#Mapper.internalMapWrapper%28org.apache.tomcat.util.http.mapper.Mapper.ContextVersion,org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.CharChunk,org.apache.tomcat.util.http.mapper.MappingData%29) which is where the mapping data of the current HTTP request is been filled with the `Context` and the `Wrapper` (essentially, an available servlet instance). It's only quite a lot of code, I won't copypaste it here, just click the grepcode link.

Then, lines 649 and 650 sets basically the mapped `Context` and `Wrapper` on the current request. The `Context` holds the concrete `ServletContext` instance and the `Wrapper` holds the concrete `Servlet` instance as a property, [`org.apache.catalina.core.Wrapper#instance`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina/7.0.42/org/apache/catalina/core/StandardWrapper.java#148).

Finally, after invoking all filters, the [`ApplicationFilterChain`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina/7.0.42/org/apache/catalina/core/ApplicationFilterChain.java#308) will invoke servlet's `service()` method.

---

For my own project, the [OmniFaces JSF utility library](http://omnifaces.org), I've ever implemented matching checks according servlet spec 12.1 in the `WebXml` utility class (in a rather simplified form). Those may be helpful for you as well, [source code is here](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/1.5/src/org/omnifaces/config/WebXml.java#L204), relevant extract below:

```
private static boolean isExactMatch(String urlPattern, String url) {
    return url.equals(urlPattern.endsWith("/*") ? urlPattern.substring(0, urlPattern.length() - 2) : urlPattern);
}

private static boolean isPrefixMatch(String urlPattern, String url) {
    return urlPattern.endsWith("/*") ? url.startsWith(urlPattern.substring(0, urlPattern.length() - 2)) : false;
}

private static boolean isSuffixMatch(String urlPattern, String url) {
    return urlPattern.startsWith("*.") ? url.endsWith(urlPattern.substring(1)) : false;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It depends on where the pattern matching is occurring.  If you are going to let JBoss(Tomcat really, Mohammad is quite correct about that) handle all the url mapping in the Web.xml and merely setup those mappings to handle request on the specific endpoints, then org.apache.naming is probably sufficient for your purposes.

Although, I would probably jump in at [NamingContext.java](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/trunk/java/org/apache/naming/NamingContext.java) as a good place to start. Not particularly exciting it handles it as you imagine it would with a HashMap for the name associations(bindings) and HashTable for object associations(context environment), still this is where the bindings and lookups happen.

However, if your are looking to handle your own routing through a front-end controller or want to redirect or re-map dynamically then the [Tomcat 8 Servlet 3.0 API](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/servletapi/) documentation might be more what you are looking for, it also is the implementation information you requested in your question.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry, but this "answer" is sheer brabbling.